# Windows folder layout

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

How can I make it so all the folders shown in the image below are shown in order?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible to sort like that. You'd have more success naming your folders YYYY-MM-DD. Alternatively, if the folders were actually created in order, you could sort by `Date Created`.

Comment: or mm-dd-yyyy....

Comment: well, yes, but that doesn't work for every instance. as long as you keep it zero padded YYYY-MM-DD will always work :)